# phpmyadmin me importa la base pero cuando inicio el programa no me muestra ningun dato

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

tengo un inconveniente, estoy trabajando en un ambiente de test tratando de migrar una versión de Mantis Bugtracker a la mas actualizada, como servidor web estoy usando XAMPP, pero tengo un problema, yo puedo exportar e importar la base datos a PHPMyadmin exitosamente pero cuando entro al sistema de Mantis (a la versión mas nueva) observo que no me trae los datos de la base que importó correctamente.

no me arroja ningún tipo de error al momento de la instalación del mantis, aparentemente me importa la base correctamente.

alguien puede saber porque si me importa la base de datos al phpmyadmin correctamente porque cuando entro al sistema no observo ningun dato importado?

Comment: Muy pocos datos para decirte algo. Verifica que los datos existan en la DB. Verifica conexión a la DB y haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Podes fijarte en el archivo .log en la carpeta PHP. Verifica la ruta de tu conexión, usuario y pass.

Answer (score 0):

En la nueva BBDD creada has puesto las mismas credenciales?
Y debes dar todos los privilegios al usuario creado.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mantisbbdd.* TO 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor realiza el [tour] y lee [answer]